# What does「ｺﾞｸﾘ」mean?

Tags: translation

I often see people use in twitter smth like「ｺﾞｸﾘ」, usually in the end of the sentence. What does it mean?

Answer (score 9):

ゴクリ (ごくり) is an onomatopoeia for swallowing down something once, in this case, saliva (**gulp**). It is used to suggest that someone sees something "tasty", or holds breath expecting something. Written in [halfwidth katakana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-width_kana) in the end of a sentence because it is a long-standing format for short text elements in Japanese memes. While the onomatopoeia has many variants like ごくっ, ごっくり etc., I have only seen it in particular forms ｺﾞｸ or ｺﾞｸﾘ as internet slang.

Comment: It's also sometimes used to indicate an anxiety/worry (e.g. after doing something wrong).

Comment: "traditional Japanese meme style", do you mean memes have a traditional style or traditional japanese is used in memes? Or something else?

Comment: I believe that broccoli means that it is in the style traditionally employed when writing memes in Japanese.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat & RebeccaNelson I'm still not sure how to put it accurately. Is the edited one clearer?